# Can you retrieve a D-Bus property without calling org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get?

Tags: dbus

Say I want to programmatically get the interface name of my ethernet card. This seems to work:

```
dbus-send --print-reply \
          --type=method_call \
          --system \
          --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
          /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0 \
          org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
          string:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device \
          string:Interface
```

Which returns:

```
method return sender=:1.5 -> dest=:1.135 reply_serial=2
   variant       string "eth0"
```

Is there some way of cutting out the middleman `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get` and retrieve the property more directly?    Alas, calling it as a method does not work:

```
dbus-send --print-reply \
          --type=method_call \
          --system \
          --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
          /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0 \
          org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Interface
```

Returns:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: 
Method "Interface" with signature "" on interface 
"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device" doesn't exist
```

I ask because having to call  `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get` looks like having to call a `object.getProp("someproperty")` instead of `object.getSomeProperty()` in Python/Java/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Most likely `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll` will return you same value, but internally every service implement properties as handlers to messages with `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get`/`org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll` method calls.

It looks like `object.getProp("someproperty")` because it actually is more like this pseudo-code

```
bus.handleMessage({
  service: "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager",
  object: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0",
  iface: "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Interface",
  body: [ "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device", "Interface"],
  thisMessageIsReplyTo: null
})
```

Internally every method call/signal/reply is just a message with big signature (service name/object path/interface) and body

Answer (score 5):

Yep, you can do that if you use **qdbus**. I don't have NetworkManager with me, but a command like that should work:

```
qdbus --system \
      org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0 \
      org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Interface
```

There are various command-line clients for talking to D-Bus, some are more convenient than others. Here's the list of the ones I know.

- `dbus-send` (provided with D-Bus itself)
- `gdbus` (provided by GLib)
- `qdbus` (provided by Qt)
- `busctl` (provided by systemd)

Comment: It's a shame that the best dbus command line tool is distributed with qt, and not dbus.

Comment: It’s worth noting that, internally, `qdbus` *will* be calling `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get` or `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll`, or getting the properties from the signals from `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager`. At the protocol level, that is a requirement.

Comment: worked for me:  

`qdbus org.kde.dolphin-2760 /dolphin/Dolphin_1 org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.isActiveWindow`